# cmd windows suddenly minimising to the taskbar

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

The past few days, whenever a cmd window opens (usually via a batch script or vbs file, but if I go to the Search box, type cmd and click on the cmd.exe result, that also does the same thing), the window opens on my desktop but immediately minimises to the taskbar. I want things back the way they were (no idea why the behaviour has changed), so that it remains up on my desktop, in its usual normal window, and I can read it. I am currently having to go down to the taskbar every time to bring it back up (which as I use quite a lot of scripting, is getting very frustrating).

If I launch the script from a shortcut, it will open normally; whereas if I click on the script file itself, it goes to the taskbar. Since many batch or vbs scripts I run are part of a larger one, they are all pointed to the .bat or .vbs script itself, not to a shortcut. For example, this extract from a vbs script, which launches the batch script from the bat file (not a shortcut to that file):

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Batch Files\FS\PF3-XP_ini.bat""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Just to be clear, I have no instruction in the script itself for this to happen and scripts that I have used for years are now all being sent to the taskbar the second they open, instead of remaining in a readable window, as they always have in the past.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with appearance (window style) setting in `Run` method? Set it to 1 like `objShell.Run("""C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Batch Files\FS\PF3-XP_ini.bat"""), 1`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have said, I tried that. Bear in mind that the same thing happens with bat files too though, not just vbs. Thanks.

Comment: StackOverFlow is for actual code related problems.  Your question is not an issue with any code you are running and should be posted on a different Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, true enough. In any case I tracked down the problem just this minute. I suddenly realised what must have happened. Sure enough, I have Windows Manager installed (which remembers window sizes on positions on multiple monitors) and the 'Freeze' option was off. So at some stage over the past few days I had obviously had a cmd window open and minimised it - WM had remembered this so that cmd windows always opened minimised thereafter. Don't know why that didn't occur to me sooner.

Luckily I had thought that this might happen and had made a backup of the WM profile. I just restored it and all is OK again.

Sorry for what in effect was a false alarm!

Comment: As I said in my comments above, StackOverFlow is for code related problems.  Not problems with software or how you have your operating system configured.  Please delete your question.

Comment: Does it do this for a console started by any app, such as running powershell.exe from Explorer? Your choice of words with "cmd window" is maybe misleading. There's no such thing as that, really. If you run powershell.exe and then cmd.exe from it, the window isn't owned by either PowerShell nor CMD. They're both just using the same console, which is really owned by conhost.exe. For UI convenience the console window says its nominal owner is the process that allocated it, until that process exits and the console shifts the nominal owner to the next process in its list of attached processes.